# How to execute codes while Tkinter mainloop for Debugging purposes

Tags: python-3.x, loops, debugging, tkinter, eval

Let's say I have this simple tkinter code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x50')
label = tk.Label(root, text='Dummy text')
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

After running it, I want to manually change the label by **executing** (`exec`/`eval`) this line: `label.configure(text='Manually changed the text!')` (or some other command) for debugging purposes.

However, during `mainloop()` I cannot execute any code in the Python Shell. How can I be able to execute the code without interrupting the `mainloop()` **and** have the effect of the code immediately be present on the Tkinter window?

Comment: You can add an `Entry` and execute the command input in the entry.

Comment: Tkinter has several user input options. `Entry`, `Text`, popup `dialog` options and even console option with the Python `input()` methods. All of which can be used to check the text in a label.

Answer (score 0):

What acw1668 suggested in code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x50')
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, command=lambda:exec(entry.get()),text='exec entry')
button.pack()
label = tk.Label(root, text='Dummy text')
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Better to execute the code in a `try` block inside a function, otherwise invalid code may crash the program.